# How to select current input field and then disable and empty the next one (and vice versa)?

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form that dynamically adds rows with 4 fields each. Like this:

[Name] [Description] [Debit] [Credit]

The expected behavior that I'm trying to accomplish is that a user can input a value only to the Debit field or only to the Credit field, but not to both. So when the user inputs a value in Debit, the Credit field should be disabled and assigned a value of 0 or empty. And vice versa, when the user inputs a value in Credit, the Debit field should be disabled and assigned a value of 0 or empty. And this should work on every row the user adds. How can I accomplish this?

So far I've been testing some alternatives but cannot make it work. Here's my current code for this part. It only disables the fields but does not empty or zero the next or previous one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $n = jQuery.noConflict();
  $n('input[name^=debits]').live("focus", function(){  
    $n('input[name^=credits]').attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $n('input[name^=debits]').removeAttr("readonly");
  });

  $n('input[name^=credits]').live("focus", function(){
    $n('input[name^=debits]').attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $n('input[name^=credits]').removeAttr("readonly");
  });
</script>
```

Thank you for any clues.

Comment: Is it possible for you to rely on .next() and .previous() in jQuery?

Comment: Can you please give me an example? Tried to use $n('input[name^=debits]').next().val(''); and $n('input[name^=credits]').prev().val(''); with no luck.

Comment: Could you please paste your HTML and stick it in jsfiddle? Then we can see the structure and if .next() / .previous() will work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $n = jQuery.noConflict();
  $n('input[name^=debits]').live("focus", function(){  
    $n(this).next('input[name^=credits]').val('').attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $n(this).removeAttr("readonly");
  });
  $n('input[name^=credits]').live("focus", function(){
      $n(this).prev('input[name^=debits]').val('').attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $n(this).removeAttr("readonly");
  });
```

Comment: Tried this but still cannot make it work. Any suggestions? Using jQuery 1.6.2.  [Here's the code](http://jsfiddle.net/kvDwj/3/). Did my best to clean the styles and show you the related part. Please bare in mind that this page also uses autocomplete for other field, sums all the debit and credit rows and mootools to load the rows.

Comment: Can you explain the issue with this code? Because this code is clearing the fields as tested in fiddle.

Comment: When having several rows it clears the values in all of them. It should work on a per row basis. [Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/EGK9h/)

Comment: Thanks! Now it worked! It didn't work at the beginning but then I realized that **when using tables, all input fields must be inside the same <td>**. So, this code works when using <td><input type="text" name="debits[]"><input type="text" name="credits[]"></td> and not when using <td><input type="text" name="debits[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="credits[]"></td>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "empty" a field, you should call `.val('')` on it

Comment: Can you please give me an example for this case? Also when having multiple rows with the same field names, .val('') applies to all of them.

Comment: You'll find an example in Abhijeet Pawar answer

Answer (score 0):

Without having much idea about the markup I have this solution for you. You might have to change the selector based on your markup.

```
  var $n = jQuery.noConflict();
  $n('input[name^=debits]').live("focus", function(){  
      $n(this)
      .prop("disabled", false);
      .parent().find('input[name^=credits]')//Assuming it has parent container
      .prop("disabled", true)
      .val(0)
  });

  $n('input[name^=credits]').live("focus", function(){
      $n(this)
      .prop("disabled", false);
      .parent().find('input[name^=debits]')//Assuming it has parent container
      .prop("disabled", true)
      .val(0);
  });
```

Note: If you want to work with input elements on the same row you should use `this` as reference or context to find the elements within the same row. What you were doing is finding all the elements on the page with required selector. Also to disable `input` box you should use `prop()` method setting it `disabled` property to `true` and vice versa to enable it.

If you are using jQuery ver 1.7+ then it is preferable to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) than `live`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add a focus handler to each input that then blanks all other input values and disables them - something like this:

```
$('table td input').focus(function(){
    // Blank all inputs first
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val(0);

    // enable the focused field
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```